Upper bound of 3APs in a set
I am looking for help with the following exercise:

For $\mu < 1$ positive, there exists $Q:=Q(\mu)$ such that for any $P> Q,$ $\exists X \subset [1, P]$ with relative (to $[1, P] $) density $\mu$ such that the number of 3-term arithmetic progressions in X has upper-bound of the type $\mu^{A \cdot log (1/\mu)} \cdot P^2$ for some A positive constant.

For the moment, I thought of using Behrend’s theorem to find subsets of $[1,R]$ free of 3-AP ($R := R(\mu, A)$) and partition $[1, P]$ in many disjoint subsets without APs strictly inside of them. Then, I could use wikipedia’s formula for the calculation of the amount of arithmetic subsets of length k of the set $\{1,...,n\}$ (under the voice ‘arithmetic progressions’) minus the 3-AP that would be in the sets of the partition. I know Roth’s theorem and Varnvide’s theorem too, but can't see a possible application here. I checked already on the site and could’t find anything similar to the question. I hope it was a thorough enough research.
